# html input type date calls javascript function before i select date in Iphone

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker

I am making a spring boot application and working with HTML to update my view. Here I am trying to implement native datepicker using `input type date` in a html form where user will select date and then the page will refresh and submit form with selected date as url parameter.

The textbox in the form will also display the value selected in datepicker in the format I require after page refresh.

Its made in such a way that there **should not be submit button** to submit form and once the user selects date from `input` field, the page should automatically refresh and save value in url parameter as well as in text box in form.

below is my code:

HTML:

```
<form action="#" id="myForm" method="get">
    <input type="text" id="save-date" name="show_date" class="form-control"> 
    <input type="date" onchange="changeDateFormat()" name="date" class="form-control"></input>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeDateFormat(){
        var received_date = document.getElementById("date-input").value;
        var split_dashes = received_date.split('-');
        var final_date = split_dashes[2]+'.'+split_dashes[1]+'.'+split_dashes[0]
        document.getElementById("show_date").value = final_date;
        document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
    }
</script>
```

**My Problem**

This works great on all the platforms except ios/iphone 8. On ios/iphone 8 as soon as i click input type date field, datepicker immediately opens and quickly refreshes the page. I expect it to wait for my input but it doesn't allow me. instead it quickly invokes js function and refreshes the page.

i dont face this in chrome or any other browser. In chrome datepicker will open as calendar and it will wait for me to select date.

**What I tried**

I tried whole night and half of my today to understand why it happens. It seems in ios datepicker it quickly selects date as soon as i click to open dropdown picker. Apart from that i tried implementing jquery function but it works the same way. I also tried `onselect`, `oninput` but nothing works.

I am beginner in javascript and this is making me go crazy from last night. I am very close to get it working but feels yet so far away.

**My Approach**
One approach to tackle this problem is on carefully observing datepicker in iphone i found out that it immediately selects date as soon as i open datepicker in the phone, and maybe that's why it invokes javascript function.

However if it can wait for me to select the date until i press "Done"(its there in iphones) in datepicker, this problem can be eliminated

Please guide me to how i can solve this

Comment: Can you check console output somehow? Which event is logged when you close the date picker? (also, why did you tag this with Java...?)

Comment: i am not able to check it. i tried to go to sources tab and look for events listener but cannot see anything.

Comment: regarding java tag.. i remember removing it, was by mistake. sorry if i have forgotten to do it.

Comment: You need to add the event logging yourself. `$('form, input').on('input, change', function () { ... });`

Comment: okay. i wrote this code 

`<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("input").on("change", function (e){
   console.log(e);
     });
 });
</script>`

and i got this output:

`w.Event {originalEvent: Event, type: "change", isDefaultPrevented: ƒ, target: input#date-input.form-control, currentTarget: input#date-input.form-control, …}`

Is this what you asking?

Comment: The point is, *when* do get it? I assume right after opening the date picker, even before you're closing it again? Because what you need to do is not submit the form in that change event in that case, and somehow detecting the change otherwise.

Comment: Hi chris. yes you are right to not to submit form in the change event. That is why i have now already solved this problem by adding `onblur` to my program instead of `onchange`

Comment: For anyone still looking to solve this, a quick workaround can be a global variable, that's updated for iOS, for example: 
`var firstClick = true;

function dateUpdate(e) {
  //mobile 
  if (window.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width: 720px)").matches){
    if (firstClick) {
      firstClick = false;
      return;
    }
//... function code
  }
}`

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who also have same problem in the future. Just try firing function with `onblur` event instead of `onchange`. onchange doesnt work here because in iphone the field gets updated as soon as you try to move the datepicker spinner to select dates. So with `onblur` it waits until the user intentionally closes the datepicker only then function is invoked.

Thanks.